# PHP Filesize direct path

Tags: php, filesize

I had created a dynamic site and our head IT person moved the directory of it messing up my coding. I have fixed everything minus the filesize. I have tried multiple tips that I have researched and it still displays nothing.

Originally it was

```
$download = $row['PDF']
```

Then later I would call it like

```
<?php
<span class = \"filesize\">(".filesize($download)." bytes)</span>";
?>
```

I have tried the following

```
  <?php
<span class = \"filesize\">(".filesize("/folder/".$download)." bytes)</span>";
?>
```

Still nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a relative path. Try this:

```
filesize("./folder/".$download)
```

Or this:

```
filesize("folder/".$download)
```

Both will start looking in the current working directory, trying to find `folder` and then the filename, instead of being accessed relative to the filesystem root.